# Convert MySQL Date to matlab datenum

Tags: mysql, matlab

I am querying a database from matlab.

The slowest part of the code is when I convert a date field into a datenum.

e.g.

```
curs = exec(conn,'select date,value from mytable')
date_string = cell2mat(curs.Data(:,1))
dn = datenum(date_string)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

--edit--

I found a faster way:

```
dn = datenum(date_string,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

But it still takes 5 seconds on my system.  Though it is 10 times faster than the previous version.

Comment: You may want to run `profile on` in the command window before executing your string, then `profile view`. You will see which of the three lines is leads to the 5 seconds.

Comment: I have the same problem. The MySQL query the datetime field as a string, not as a date serial number, hence, you require about 1 second per 100 database rows. Anybody knows how to make MATLAB take the date as a number directly -which is the logical, since the datetime is also natively a double.